# The customized nz-modal css still has an effect even the related component is destroyed

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

I am using nz-modal of ng-zorro in different components, every component will render a customized CSS effect(eg. different height, background, and color...), **After switching to another component, seems the original modal CSS doesn't appear, that doesn't work as expected.**

I attached a partial code in below since the whole length is too long,
I had edit-panel.component.html, edit-elec-module.component.html, edit-signal.component.html, each of them has a different CSS to render their modal visual effect, but when I switch between the three components, the original CSS still works for current component, I could see original CSS in F12 debugging mode in browser... picture also attached.

New to angular and nz-zorro, thanks for any help...

[image]

interface-setting.component.html:

```
<div class="container" *transloco="let t">
    <div class="title-box">
        <div class="box">
            接口设置
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="env-title">
        <div class="general" (click)="changeCurrentView('panel')"
            [ngClass]="{selected: isPanelSelected, disabled: !isPanelSelected}">面板</div>
        <div class="ignored" (click)="changeCurrentView('device')"
            [ngClass]="{selected: isDeviceSelected, disabled: !isDeviceSelected}">设备</div>
        <div class="ignored" (click)="changeCurrentView('signal')"
            [ngClass]="{selected: isSignalSelected, disabled: !isSignalSelected}">信号</div>
    </div>

    <app-general-panel *ngIf="currentView=='panel'"></app-general-panel>
    <app-general-signal *ngIf="currentView=='signal'"></app-general-signal>
    <app-general-elec-module *ngIf="currentView=='device'"></app-general-elec-module>
</div>
```

general-panel.component.html

```
<section class="box" *transloco="let t">

    <div class="box1">
        <div class="panel_list">面板列表</div>
        <div class="panel_add" (click)="editPanel.open_add()"><img src="assets/images/imgs/接口-添加.png" alt="editor">添加面板
        </div>
        <div class="search_box">
            <input type="text" class="search_input" placeholder="搜索面板" [(ngModel)]="input_value"
                (keyup)="($event.which === 13)?onClickData(''):0">
        </div>
    </div>

    <nz-table light [nzData]="panels!" [nzFrontPagination]="false" [nzLoading]="loading" [nzTotal]="total"
        [nzPageSize]="pageSize" [nzPageIndex]="pageIndex" (nzQueryParams)="onQueryParamsChange($event)"
        *transloco="let t">
        <thead>
            <tr class="table-body" light>
                <th class="table-head first_col">
                    序号
                </th>
                <th class="table-head">
                    面板名称
                </th>
                <th class="table-head third_col">
                    操作
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let data of panels" class="table-body" light>
                <td class="first_col">
                    <div>
                        {{data.id}}
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="second_col">
                    <div>
                        {{data.name}}
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="third_col">
                    <div class="operation">
                        <button light nz-button nzSize="small" nzGhost="true" class="ignore"
                            (click)="editPanel.open_edit(data)">编辑</button>
                        <span class="divide"></span>
                        <button light nz-button nzSize="small" nzGhost="true" class="ignore"
                            (click)="delete(data)">删除</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </nz-table>
</section>

<app-edit-panel #editPanel></app-edit-panel>
```

edit-panel.component.html

```
<nz-modal [(nzVisible)]="isVisible" (nzOnCancel)="handleCancel()" (nzOnOk)="handleOk()" nzTitle={{faultSettingTitle}}
    [nzWidth]='432' [nzOkLoading]="isOkLoading">
    <ng-container *nzModalContent>
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box1">
                <ul>
                    <li class="name">
                        面板名称：
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input nz-input placeholder="请输入" [(ngModel)]="name" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="box2">
                <ul>
                    <li class="name">
                        面板位置：
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input nz-input placeholder="请输入" [(ngModel)]="loc" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="box3">
                <ul>
                    <li class="name">
                        面板连接：
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input nz-input placeholder="请输入" [(ngModel)]="connector" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="box4">
                <ul>
                    <li class="name">
                        面板厂商：
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input nz-input placeholder="请输入" [(ngModel)]="manufacture" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="box5">
                <ul>
                    <li class="name">
                        面板编号：
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input nz-input placeholder="请输入" [(ngModel)]="id" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
    <div *nzModalFooter>
        <div *ngIf="isValidInput()">
            <button nz-button nzType="default" (click)="handleCancel()" class="cancel_bn">取消</button>
            <button nz-button nzType="primary" (click)="handleOk()" [nzLoading]="isOkLoading">提交</button>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!isValidInput()">
            <button nz-button nzType="default" (click)="handleCancel()" class="cancel_bn">取消</button>
            <button nz-button nzType="primary" class="invalid_bn">提交</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nz-modal>
```

edit-panel.component.css

```
::ng-deep .ant-modal-content {
    height: 576px !important;
    background: rgba(36, 40, 48, 1) !important;
}

.box {
    height: 444px !important;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

::ng-deep svg {
    color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
}

ul li {
    color: rgb(242, 242, 242);
    font-size: 13px;
}

.box1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

::ng-deep .ant-radio-button-wrapper {
    margin-left: 8px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    border: 0 !important;
}

.ant-radio-button-wrapper:not(:first-child)::before {
    content: none;
}

::ng-deep .ant-input {
    width: 400px;
    height: 35px;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-top: 8px !important;
    /* margin-right: 20px !important; */
    padding-left: 12px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
    color: white;
    /* background-color: #2e2e2f; */
    border: none;
    background-color: rgba(30, 32, 36, 1) !important;
}

::ng-deep .ant-modal-body {
    padding: 0;
}

::ng-deep .ant-modal-header {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    height: 71px;
    margin-left: 16px;
    margin-right: 16px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) !important;
}

::ng-deep .ant-modal-title {
    color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1);
    line-height: 40px;
}

::ng-deep .ant-modal-close-x {
    width: 52px;
    height: 72px;
    /* margin-right: 20px; */
    line-height: 72px;
}

ul {
    padding-inline-start: 16px;
}

.name {
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 14px !important;
    color: rgba(179, 179, 179, 1) !important;
}

::placeholder {
    color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 1);
}

::ng-deep .ant-modal-footer {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) !important;
    padding-top: 12px !important;
    padding-bottom: 12px !important;
    padding-left: 16px !important;
    padding-right: 16px !important;
}

::ng-deep .ant-btn {
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: transparent;
}

::ng-deep .ant-btn {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1);
    background-color: rgba(101, 150, 204, 1);
    border-color: transparent;
}

::ng-deep .ant-btn:hover {
    background-color: rgba(81, 122, 166, 1);
}

.cancel_bn {
    color: rgba(242, 242, 242, 1);
    border-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 1);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.cancel_bn:hover {
    color: rgba(101, 150, 204, 1);
    border-color: rgba(101, 150, 204, 1);
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.invalid_bn {
    background-color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 1) !important;
    border-color: transparent !important;
}

.invalid_bn:hover {
    cursor: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to customize content nz-modal by CSS you can use a Property called ***nzBodyStyle***

nzBodyStyle : Body style for modal body element. Such as height, padding etc.

[image]

and value it must be object contain property of css like thsi `{'height':'576px}`

so when adding this property to the modal code it will be like this

```
<nz-modal  
[nzBodyStyle]="{
      'height':'576px',
      'background':' rgba(36, 40, 48, 1)',
      'color':'red'}" >
..........
...........
...........
</nz-modal>
```